# When/How to use backticks and single quotes in mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
mysql_query("select ip from table1 where ip=$ip",$conn);*NOT work*  
mysql_query("select ip from table1 where ip='$ip'",$conn);*work*
```

what's the problem?

Comment: You sure the first query of `q1` didn't work ? Because the other two are obviously erroneous..

Comment: in q1, you can notice that ` added to times and ip then can work.

Comment: and ,you say obviously erroneous. i am so low because i cannot understand where is the error

Comment: Yeah I see that.. but look at second query of `q3` , It doesn't have backtick.. so how did it work ? ;)

Comment: in q3, it really work, can select the value from mysql. it seemed you also confused.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran :) really contradiction , q1 dont work and q3 work while they are same in quotes and backticks :). she must have some problems in here code. not the query

Answer (score 2):

As documented under [Schema Object Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html):

> Certain objects within MySQL, including database, table, index, column, alias, view, stored procedure, partition, tablespace, and other object names are known as identifiers.
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you *must* quote it whenever you refer to it. (Exception: A reserved word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted.) Reserved words are listed at [Section 9.3, “Reserved Words”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html).
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`` ` ``”):
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT * FROM `select` WHERE `select`.id > 100;
> ```
>
> If the [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks:
>
> ```
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...
> mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
> ```

As documented under [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html):

> A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote (“`'`”) or double quote (“`"`”) characters. Examples:
>
> ```
> 'a string'
> "another string"
> ```
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> If the [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode is enabled, string literals can be quoted only within single quotation marks because a string quoted within double quotation marks is interpreted as an identifier.

[Number Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/number-literals.html) should not be quoted (although MySQL will usually cope if they are, as it will perform suitable [type conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/type-conversion.html)); [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html) may require quoting, depending on the format used.

Calls to [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/functions.html) must *never* be quoted, as otherwise they will be parsed as string literals.

Answer (score 2):

**in q2:**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1 (ip,addtime) VALUES ('$ip','CURDATE()')",$conn);
```

you inserting 'CURDATE()' as string while this is mysql function and should be without quotes.

when you insert it will be insered as CURDATE() and not 2014-04-....

**in q3:**

```
mysql_query("select ip from table1 where ip=$ip",$conn);
```

when you insert ip it will be like that:

```
 mysql_query("select ip from table1 where ip= 12.155.155.14 ",$conn);
```

which is not valid so you must insert it as string

```
mysql_query("select ip from table1 where ip='12.155.155.14'",$conn);
```

**in q1:**

```
 mysql_query("update table1 set `times`='2' where `ip`='$ip'");
```

no one of your columns is reserved keyword , so they should work otherwise its you should escape them by backticks . But it nice your first query so it should work.

EDIT:

in q1 , i dont think it fails with just backticks `ip` and `times` it must work. because either ip ,or times column names are nice(Not reserved keywords or containing some spaces or somespecial characters) with backticks or without. In general it nice to use backticks in column , table, database names.

Comment: +1 for explaining them beautifully...  but you still didn't explain why the first query of `q1` failed ;)

Comment: in q1 , i dont think it fails with just backticks `ip` it must work. because either ip ,or times column names are nice(Not reserved keywords or containg some spaces or somespecial characters) with backticks or without.

Comment: That is what my question is .. OP said it failed also see my [**first comment**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890485/error-of-mysql-query-in-php-script-about/22890606?noredirect=1#comment34931031_22890485) on this post.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran yeah i saw that :) , and i knew you went through all 3 queries and you considered just first query which is strange if didnt work :).

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use ` symbol wherever you use MySQL column name or db name or tablename.

And use ' whenever you define the value.

Cover your query with "" .

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dbname`.`tablename` WHERE `columnname`='$value' ");
```

Comment: follow your rule, you can find when ' added to CURDATE() in q2, it NOT work.

Comment: and, i saw lots of sample without `,' through GOOGLE, then i am really confused , what's the real rule??crazy

Comment: It wont work, since CURDATE() is a mysql function, you should leave as it is.. No ' or ` or " for all mysql functions in a query

Comment: @NiceGirl, The **real rule** is .. if your table column names falls under [**reserved words**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) then you need to surround it with backticks.